# How to write a Room Database Adapter to wrap result type

Tags: android, database, adapter, android-room

What i want to achieve is to wrap a specific type for room database query result

The same as we doing now with android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2 library that helps to expose RxJava2 Types like Observables and Flowables in the result

example :

```
abstract Single<User> find(String id);
```

Is there any specific Adapter or a way that can help to acheive this wrapping ? or create and artifact same as android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2

for Coroutines as an example

Comment: Your question is very unclear. If you are asking "is there a documented way for us to create our own artifacts that operate akin to `android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2`, to offer alternative reactive return types?", the answer is no, at least not today.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes you answered my question, i need to edit my question because it wasn't that clear, thanks

Comment: You might look at the Room source code and see what `android.arch.persistence.room:compiler` knows about RxJava code generation. It is possible that they have worked out some undocumented delegation system whereby `android.arch.persistence.room:compiler` knows *nothing* about RxJava, by means of having some code generation be handled by ``android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2`. If so, you could attempt to mimic the same thing for Kotlin coroutines. Or, you could create a Kotlin coroutines implementation that works with a modified `compiler` and contribute it to the Room project.

Comment: @CommonsWare good advice i will try to follow your suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Add `implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.1.0"` to you build.gradle.

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#query-rxjava

```
@Dao
    public interface MyDao {
    @Query("SELECT * from user where id = :id LIMIT 1")
    public Flowable<User> loadUserById(int id);
}
```